# В этом предложении сказуемое простое или составное? Помогите определиться

Tags: синтаксис

Он стремился захватить землю соседа.

Answer (score 1):

Это составное глагольное сказуемое, где "стремился" - вспомогательный глагол

Answer (score 1):

Согласна с Виктором. Он стремился захватить землю соседа.-составное глагольное.

Как отличить инфинитив в составном глагольном сказуемом от инфинитива - дополнения? Инфинитив в сказуемом обозначает действие подлежащего и называется субъектным,инфинитивное дополнение называет действие другого действующего лица и называется объектным. Он стремился и он будет захватывать -сказуемое. Он велел (что?)захватить землю соседа - он велел, а захватывать будет другой - сказуемое велел, дополнение захватить.

Comment: почему тогда "поедет учиться" - простое сказуемое. Ведь оба действия относятся к одному лицу?

Comment: Он что сделает?-поедет(прост.глаг.). Зачем? - учиться(обст.).При глаголах движения инфинитив часто бывает обстоятельством цели.(Мужик гнал гусей продавать в город.-гнал зачем?-продавать)

Comment: Здесь тоже можно сказать: стремился к чему? - захватить (т.е. к захвату. Но среди вспомогательных глаголов есть такие, которые имеют значение "возможность или желательность действия". В этом списке данного глагола нет, но он близок к глаголам "хотеть", "желать"

Answer (score 1):

Отличать инфинитив в составном глагольном сказуемом от инфинитива в роли обстоятельства или дополнения лучше путем грамматического анализа, определяя ТЕМАТИКУ вспомогательных глаголов. В роли вспомогательных глаголов могут выступать: а) фазовые глаголы; б) глаголы с модальным значением; в) фразеологизмы с модальным значением, например: перестал слушать, начал сомневаться, решил уехать, сумел убедить, любил ездить, горит желанием показать.

Глаголы ДВИЖЕНИЯ сюда не относятся, это тема составного именного сказуемого, например: "Он увидел свою бричку, которая стояла совсем готовая".

Информация о субъектном и объектном инфинитиве в роли дополнения (обстоятельства):
http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-147.htm

Они условились (о чем)встретиться завтра (субъектный инфинитив в роди дополнения).
Я прошу вас (о чем) прочесть статью (объектный инфинитив в роли дополнения).